# Aplicar el resultado de la distancia de caracteres

Tags: r

Tengo dos df con multitud de columnas. Las resumo en las dos siguientes df:

```
d1=data.frame(col1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
              col2=c("rojo34","verde","amarillo","amarillo 23","pepe","marta","lento"),
              col3=c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G"))

d2=data.frame(col1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
              col2=c("ve4ttrde","nada de nada", "amareillo56","rojo","pepe","martitta","rapido"),
              col3=c("FFF","BBB","CCC","AAA","EEE","GGG","DDD"))
```

**d1**

```
        col1    col2   col3
        1      rojo34    A
        2       verde    B
        3    amarillo    C
        4 amarillo 23    D
        5        pepe    E
        6       marta    F
        7       lento    G
```

**d2**

```
col1    col2 col3
1     ve4ttrde  FFF
2 nada de nada  BBB
3  amareillo56  CCC
4         rojo  AAA
5         pepe  EEE
6     martitta  GGG
7       rapido  DDD
```

Quiero encontrar la similitud que hay en la col2 de ambos df.
Para ello recurro a la distancia de Jaro-Winkler.

```
library(stringdist)

d <- expand.grid(d1$col2,d2$col2)

d$dist <- stringdist(d$Var1,d$Var2, method="jw")

do.call(rbind, unname(by(d, d$Var1, function(x) x[x$dist <0.25,])))->similares



         Var1        Var2       dist
17    amarillo amareillo56 0.09090909
18 amarillo 23 amareillo56 0.18181818
41       marta    martitta 0.12500000
33        pepe        pepe 0.00000000
22      rojo34        rojo 0.11111111
2        verde    ve4ttrde 0.12500000
```

Entonces ya tengo quien de d1 se parece a d2. Ahora quiero aplicar esto a los df.

La duda es como fusiono d1 y d2 para que se formen esas uniones, dejando un df que sería algo como esto:

```
  d1.col1     d1.col2    d1.col3     d2.col2        d2.col3
    1        rojo34         A        rojo             AAA
    2        verde          B        ve4ttrde         FFF
    3        amarillo       C        amareillo56      CCC
    4        amarillo 23    D        amareillo56      CCC
    5        pepe           E        pepe             EEE
    6       marta           F        martitta         GGG
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar tu tabla `similares` como pivote para dos `inner_joins`:

```
library(tidyverse)

similares %>% 
  filter(dist < 0.25) %>% 
  inner_join(d1, by=c("Var1"="col2")) %>% 
  inner_join(d2, by=c("Var2"="col2"))

         Var1        Var2       dist col1.x col3.x col1.y col3.y
1      rojo34        rojo 0.11111111      1      A      4    AAA
2       verde    ve4ttrde 0.12500000      2      B      1    FFF
3    amarillo amareillo56 0.09090909      3      C      3    CCC
4 amarillo 23 amareillo56 0.18181818      4      D      3    CCC
5        pepe        pepe 0.00000000      5      E      5    EEE
6       marta    martitta 0.12500000      6      F      6    GGG
```

Pero, para esto en particular, es muy cómodo usar [`fuzzyjoin`](http://library(tidyverse))

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fuzzyjoin)

d1 %>% 
  stringdist_inner_join(d2, by="col2", method = "jw", max_dist=.25)
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta es una opción usando `tidyverse`. Le cambié los nombres a las columnas porque si tienes los mismos nombres en ambos se complican los joins del final.

```
d1=data.frame(col1a=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
              col2a=c("rojo34","verde","amarillo","amarillo 23","pepe","marta","lento"),
              col3a=c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G"))

d2=data.frame(col1b=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
              col2b=c("ve4ttrde","nada de nada", "amareillo56","rojo","pepe","martitta","rapido"),
              col3b=c("FFF","BBB","CCC","AAA","EEE","GGG","DDD"))

crossing(col2a = d1$col2a, col2b = d2$col2b) %>% #Producto cartesiano, simil a expand.grid pero permite manejar nombres
  mutate(distancia = stringdist(col2a, col2b, method = "jw")) %>%   #Calculo la distancia de cada par
  filter(distancia < 0.25) -> para_filtro   #Me quedo con las distancias menores

para_filtro %>% 
  left_join(d1) %>% #Al ser left_join solo quedan las filas del df a la izquierda, en este caso el que está filtrado por distancias 
  left_join(d2)  #Agrego las demás columnas
```

Obtengo

```
col2a       col2b       distancia col1a col3a col1b col3b
<chr>       <chr>           <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
1 amarillo    amareillo56    0.0909     3 C         3 CCC  
2 amarillo 23 amareillo56    0.182      4 D         3 CCC  
3 marta       martitta       0.125      6 F         6 GGG  
4 pepe        pepe           0          5 E         5 EEE  
5 rojo34      rojo           0.111      1 A         4 AAA  
6 verde       ve4ttrde       0.125      2 B         1 FFF
```

Comment: Gracias a los dos!!! Está claro que sois los reyes de R.